# Gemfire and HBase Connector

Tags: spring, hbase, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I want to build Gemfire to/from HBase connectors for real time data inserts from GemFire to Hbase and vice-versa ,any pointer on this would be a great help.
Basic requirement is to evict data into Hbase, expired data should flush to Hbase and if cache miss happens data should pulled from Hbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by implementing the [CacheListener](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/CacheListener.html) and [CacheLoader](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/CacheLoader.html) interfaces, respectively.  You can register 1 or more CacheListeners along with a CacheLoader on the Region(s) tied to HBase.  I am not sure what event is fired during "eviction", but during "expiration", the [afterInvalidate](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/CacheListener.html#afterInvalidate(com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.EntryEvent)) is triggered.

See the GemFire UG on [Eviction](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/eviction/how_eviction_works.html), [Expiration](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/expiration/how_expiration_works.html), [Syncing with Outside DataSources](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html), [Events and Event Handling](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/events/how_events_work.html), and specifically, [Event Handlers](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/developing/events/list_of_event_handlers_and_events.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks John, I am using the same what you have mentioned above.